# How can I get rows after a specific row, from a resultset of a specific sort order?

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a table that has an `ID` column of type `varchar(255)` as the primary key. The rest of the columns comprise of `text`, `datetime` and `varchar(255)` types. Let's consider the given query:

```
SELECT ID from `table` 
where (certain condition)    
order by    
    columnX,
    columnY,
    ID
limit 10
;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause has the specified columns sorted in an ascending order for this example, but it could contain mixed directions (both ASC & DESC). Anyway, executing the above query gives me a `resultset` like this:

```
27087675-38b5-41ea-afa5-9cf24c388545
770a933d-064f-41f5-8d2a-55acaedf38bf
a2e509e3-3a61-44e6-a36e-955d7b1f7b5e
19c47c26-075f-4761-a462-02025f4b29ce
ab3418ee-0b26-40ec-87b8-2b3636bb4e59
24caf7cb-fca5-45f0-81a0-f97175d8e071
285295fb-4ba7-4a70-9aaa-0a93cac058e8
f976e378-394f-42ed-af07-012336660546
5c0201c4-4aec-4e48-95c8-91e73b7843ee
de8f6adf-f880-4758-aeda-9e66a308bbc0
```

The `resultset` consists of `10` elements (for the sake of brevity). Now, what I'm trying to achieve, is to get the elements after a certain `ID`, in the same order. For example, if I want to get the elements after `ab3418ee-0b26-40ec-87b8-2b3636bb4e59`, the output should be

```
24caf7cb-fca5-45f0-81a0-f97175d8e071
285295fb-4ba7-4a70-9aaa-0a93cac058e8
f976e378-394f-42ed-af07-012336660546
5c0201c4-4aec-4e48-95c8-91e73b7843ee
de8f6adf-f880-4758-aeda-9e66a308bbc0
```

What I tried:

- I tried the condition `AND ID > 'ab3418ee-0b26-40ec-87b8-2b3636bb4e59'` in the `WHERE` clause, without any luck.
- It kinda works when I use the first column in the `ORDER BY` clause with the comparison operator, for example `AND columnX > 'someValue'`, but if the `ORDER BY` clause contains mixture of `ASC & DESC`, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to solve this? I basically want to split the `resultset`, which will always have some kind of `ORDER`. I just want to load the elements after a certain `ID`, regardless of the sort order. Could really use some help with this.

Comment: add a row number to the select and then get the rownumber , you wish to select from, it will get ugly but works

Comment: @nbk I've already successfully tried the `rownumber` approach. I just wanted to see if it can be solved without using the temporary `rownumber` column.

Comment: no, if you want to have a forcest order, you need a column that keeps the order, rownumber is the simplest solution

Comment: @nbk is there any link that I can refer to?

Comment: for whar exactly?

Comment: @nbk for this rownumber implementation that you told about.

Comment: @nbk if what you meant was `ROW_NUMBER()` function, unfortunately, I'm working with mysql 5.6, which doesn't have that feature

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A**. You need the entire set of columns that you are ordering by.  Let's say you left off at `a=4 AND b=11 AND c=2`

If you are going ascending, then

```
WHERE (a, b, c) > (4, 11, 2)
```

For *all* DESC, change to `<`

Caveat:  "row constructors" like that were not optimized until 5.7.

For a mixture, please provide a 2-column example *without UUIDs*.  Provide `CREATE TABLE` and sample data.  Preferrably ready to run in a 'fiddle'.

**Plan B**  This is like the row_number(), which is not available before 8.0.

Create a table with a new `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  If all the work is in a single connection, use a `TEMPORARY TABLE`.  Then lean on that new id for "remembering where you left off".